# Why Am I Getting An NPE That Only Appears Occasionally When The Program is Run?

Tags: java, debugging, junit, bluej

I'm writing a test class for my `GiftSelector` class using JUnit in BlueJ. When I run the `testGetCountForAllPresents()` method, I get a `NullPointerException` on the line:

```
assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(banana) == 3);
```

The strange thing about this NPE, is that it rarely appears when I run the test once, but often appears the second time I run the test. It sometimes doesn't appear until I've ran the test 7-8 times consecutively.

The error message I'm getting is:
no exception message.

> NPE at line 215 in GiftSelectortest.testGetCountForAllPresents

The code for my test class is:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * The test class GiftSelectorTest. The GiftSelector that you are 
 * testing must have testMode enabled for this class to function. 
 * This is done in the setUp() method.
 */
public class GiftSelectorTest
{
    private GiftList giftList1;
    private GiftList giftList2;
    private GiftList giftList3;
    private Child jack;
    private Child bob;
    private Child dave;
    private Child naughty1;
    private GiftSelector santasSelector;
    private Present banana1;
    private Present orange;
    private Present banana;
    private Present apple;
    private Present bike;
    private Present doll;
    private Present got;
    private Present pearlHarbour;
    private Present dog;
    private Present cat;
    private Present ball;
    private Present heineken;

    /**
     * Default constructor for test class GiftSelectorTest
     */
    public GiftSelectorTest()
    {
        //Nothing to do here...
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the test fixture.
     *
     * Called before every test case method.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        santasSelector = new GiftSelector();
        santasSelector.setTestMode(true);
        jack = new Child("Jack", 20, "1 A Place", true, true, true, false);
        bob = new Child("Bob", 10, "2 A Place", true, true, true, true);
        dave = new Child("Dave", 10, "3 A Place", true, true, true, true);
        naughty1 = new Child("John", 5, "4 A Place", true, true, true, true);
        giftList1 = new GiftList(jack);
        giftList2 = new GiftList(bob);
        giftList3 = new GiftList(dave);
        banana = new Present("banana", "fruit", 10);
        orange = new Present("orange", "fruit", 10);
        banana1 = new Present("banana", "fruit", 10);
        apple = new Present("apple", "fruit", 10);
        bike = new Present("bike", "toy", 200);
        doll = new Present("doll", "toy", 40);
        got = new Present("game of thrones", "dvd", 50);
        pearlHarbour = new Present("pearl harbour", "dvd", 20);
        dog = new Present("dog", "animal", 100);
        cat = new Present("cat", "animal", 80);
        ball = new Present("ball", "toy", 5);
        heineken = new Present("heineken", "beer", 1.60);
    }

    /**
     * Tears down the test fixture.
     *
     * Called after every test case method.
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        //Nothing to do here...
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetCountForAllPresents()
    {
        System.out.println(santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents());
        //Test on empty GiftSelector
        assertNull(santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents());

        //Test on a GiftSelector with one giftlist containing one present
        giftList1.addPresent(banana);
        santasSelector.addGiftList(giftList1);
        System.out.println(santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents());
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(banana) == 1);

        //Test when GiftSelector contains 2 giftlists, each containing the same present object

        giftList2.addPresent(banana);
        santasSelector.addGiftList(giftList2);
        System.out.println(santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents());
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(banana) == 2);

        //Test when GiftSelector contains 3 giftlists, 2 containing the same present object and another containing an identical present but with a different present instance
        giftList3.addPresent(banana1);
        santasSelector.addGiftList(giftList3);
        System.out.println(santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents());
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(banana) == 3); //This is the line I get the NPE

        //Test when GiftSelector contains 3 giftLists, the first with one with a banana, the second with a banana and apple, and the third with a banana1 and ball
        giftList2.addPresent(apple);
        giftList3.addPresent(ball);
        System.out.println(santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents());
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(banana) == 3);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(apple) == 1);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(ball) == 1);

    }


    @Test
    public void testGetMostPopularPresent()
    {
        //Test on empty GiftSelector
        assertNull(santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent());

        //Test on a GiftSelector with one giftList and one Present
        giftList1.addPresent(heineken);
        santasSelector.addGiftList(giftList1);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent().comparePresent(heineken));

        //Tset on a GiftSelector with 1 giftList and 2 presents, one more expensive than the other
        giftList1.addPresent(banana);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent().comparePresent(banana));

        //Test on a GiftSelector with 1 giftList and 3 presents. Banana and Apple are equal in price, and are both in the top3, 
        //therefore it should return the present closest to the start of the list
        giftList1.addPresent(apple);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent().comparePresent(banana) || santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent().comparePresent(apple));

        //Test on a GiftSelector with 2 giftLists, the second list containing banana1, an indentical present to banana
        giftList2.addPresent(banana1);
        santasSelector.addGiftList(giftList2);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent().comparePresent(banana));

        //Test on a GiftSelector with 2 giftLists, the first containing four presents and the second containing 2 presents.
        //This tests to see if top3 is working.
        giftList1.addPresent(bike);
        giftList2.addPresent(bike);
        assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getMostPopularPresent().comparePresent(bike));
    }
}
```

I've included only the test methods that reference the `getCountsForAllPresents()` method. You'll notice that I've added print statements before each call to an `assertEquals()` method containing the `getCountForAllPresents()` method. What's interesting is that before the line where I get the NPE, the print statement prints out the correct value for the `HashMap` returned by `getCountForAllPresents()`.

The only other strange thing that I've noticed, is that when I go through the `testGetCountForAllPresents()` method using BlueJ's built in debugger, I notice that `giftList3` doesn't appear in the `santaMap` `HashMap` in `santasSelector`, yet the print statement still prints the correct counting, implying it must know about `giftList3`.

The code for `getCountForAllPresents()` is:

```
/**
 * For each present, calculate the total number of children who have asked for that present.
 * 
 * @return - a Map where Present objects are the keys and Integers (number of children requesting
 * a particular present) are the values. Returns null if santaMap is empty.
 */
public HashMap<Present, Integer> getCountsForAllPresents()
{
    if(!santaMap.isEmpty()) {
        //This HashMap contains a mapping from each unique real world present, represented by it's toComparisonString(), to a Present object representing it
        HashMap<String, Present> uniquePresents = new HashMap<String, Present>();
        //This HashMap contains a mapping from each Present object in uniquePresents to the number of times it's toComparisonString() is equal to another in santaMap
        HashMap<Present, Integer> presentFrequency = new HashMap<Present, Integer>();

         for(GiftList wishlist: santaMap.values()) {
            for(Present present: wishlist.getAllPresents()) {
                //Have we already seen this present?
                if(uniquePresents.containsKey(present.toComparisonString())) {
                    //If so, update the count in presentFrequency
                    Integer tmp = presentFrequency.get(uniquePresents.get(present.toComparisonString()));
                    tmp++;
                    presentFrequency.put(uniquePresents.get(present.toComparisonString()), tmp);
                } else {
                    //If not, add it to the maps uniquePresents and presentFrequency (with a frequency of 1)
                    uniquePresents.put(present.toComparisonString(), present);
                    presentFrequency.put(present, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        //Return a map with unique presents as keys and their frequencies as values
        return presentFrequency;
    }
    else {
        //If there are no mappings in Santa's map, return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

I should explain that `santaMap` is a `HashMap`, with a `Child` object as key and a `GiftList` object as the value. It basically maps a child to their christmas wishlist. A `santaMap` can contain only one wishlist by the same child.

I've no idea why I'm getting the NPE, is it something to do with how I've written the `getCountForAllPresents()` method? How I've implemented the test method/class?

Comment: Can you add the code for `Present`?

Comment: where is the line 215 you get null at?

Comment: I think the full code of `GiftSelector` might be a good addition

Comment: Since I've removed some code, the line number won't correspond. If you look at the testGetCountForAllPresents() method, go to the second last block of code and you should see the line `assertEquals(true, santasSelector.getCountsForAllPresents().get(banana) == 3);` That is where I get the NPE. It should have a comment next to it saying "this is where I get the NPE"

Comment: Did you try to add a breakpoint or something to see if `santasSelector` or the `getCountsForAllPresents` is the item coming back as NULL? Perhaps post the full NPE error you're getting?

Comment: The error message I posted is all that I'm getting back from BlueJ. SantaSelector is created in the test Fixture setUp() method. The santaMap in SantaSelector is only null when no giftLists have been added to it. however santaMap always contains giftList1 and giftList2 before I get the NPE, however as I mentioned in the post, giftList3, doesn't seem to appear in santaMap, despite it being added, yet when I print out getCountForAllPresents(), it prints the correct values, showing that it must somehow have taken giftList3 into account

Comment: NPE + one-liners = headaches.  Decompose your code into a few lines to see where the NPE is actually hitting.  I would guess however that you have a Child in your santaMap that has a null GiftList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Present` class does not override `hashCode()` and `equals()`. This means that `banana1` and `banana` are two distinct keys in any `HashMap` that will use them as a key.

So let's see what happens here. You have the `banana` and the `banana1` objects - two of the first, one of the second.

Inside `getCountsForAllPresents()` you have the two hash maps. The first goes by the comparison string of the objects, and the second - by the objects themselves.

You add the first banana you encounter. If it is the `banana` object, you'll have something like this:

```
uniquePresents
banana-fruit-10 ➞ [banana instance]

presentFrequency
[banana instance] ➞ Integer(1)
```

You continue to iterate. You encounter the next `banana` object. It's the same object. You'll get:

```
uniquePresents
banana-fruit-10 ➞ [banana instance]

presentFrequency
[banana instance] ➞ Integer(2)
```

Now you get to the `banana1` object. It's a different object, but it has the same comparison string! What happens?

This condition is true: `uniquePresents.containsKey(present.toComparisonString())`. This means it goes into the true part of the `if`.

```
Integer tmp = presentFrequency.get(uniquePresents.get(present.toComparisonString()));
```

This means it will take the object currently pointed to by `banana-fruit-10`, which is the **`banana`** object - not the `banana1` object, get its associated frequency, and increment it. It also stores by the same object. What you have now is:

```
uniquePresents
banana-fruit-10 ➞ [banana instance]

presentFrequency
[banana instance] ➞ Integer(3)
```

Note that `presentFrequency` does not have a `banana1` key at all. And now you return this object.

When you try to retrieve by `banana`, it works OK - the assert works.

But remember, `santaMap` itself is a `HashMap`. This means there is no guaranteed order on it. The iterator may give you `giftList1`,`giftList2`,`giftList3`, but it may also give you `giftList3`,`giftList1`,`giftList2` - or any other order.

So what happens when it gives you `giftList3` first? You`ll end up with:

```
uniquePresents
banana-fruit-10 ➞ [banana1 instance]

presentFrequency
[banana1 instance] ➞ Integer(3)
```

Why? Because `banana1` was the first gift with the key `banana-fruit-10`, and that's what it will use from now on.

When this happens, when you try to get `banana` from the returned object, that key does not exist in the frequency list. It returns `null` - and there is your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so clearly. Do you see any way to fix this so that it always returns the correct answer? I'm fairly new to programming, so I haven't covered method overriding and other OO features yet, Is there are better solution than to override hashCode() and Equals() in Present?

Comment: Well, not if you are going to use these objects as keys in a hash map. But perhaps you can use something else, like an object that contains a hash map (keyed by the comparison string), and has a `get` method that takes a `Present` object as parameter, and returns the frequency from the internal hash map by its comparison string. Then use that object as the return type of `getCountsForAllPresents()`.